# Bash script to install dependencies and provide status feedback

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a bash script to install packages and provide feedback, e.g. "Processing package: gcc, Package 1 of 17".  I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

dep_ubuntu = "dep1 dep2 dep3 dep4 dep5"

length=$(echo $dep_ubuntu | wc -w)

for pkg in $dep_ubuntu; do
    echo "Processing ${pkg}, Package $pkg of $length"
done
```

When I try to run this code, I experience "line 3: dep_ubuntu: command not found".  Am I using the wrong types of quotes to declare this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the spaces around the `=`:

```
dep_ubuntu="dep1 dep2 dep3 dep4 dep5"
```

Comment: Yes, I just figured this out.  I'm new to Bash.  I can't believe this was it.  Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I can't have a space between the variable and data.